# How do I place four "evenly" spaced lines along the perimeter of a shape in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, path

I have the following shape, which I made by creating an ellipse and scaling the top and bottom handles at the same time with the s shortcut. On this shape, I want to place four spaced out lines that follow the perimeter.

[image: shape I have]

I have roughly drawn what I want to create:

[image: what I want to create]

This is similar to the "square four corners" structure, which is familiar to me from camera focus icons:

[image: square four corners]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the shape and....

- `Object > Path > Offset Path`

[image]

- Swap the fill/stroke on this new path and set the stroke weight

[image]

- Draw two rectangles across the shapes, one vertical and one horizontal
- align everything on center vertical and horizontal.

[image]

- Select the rectangles and the outer path
- Grab the **Shape Builder Tool**
- Hold down the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key and click-drag across the rectangles.
- Use the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow) to click the resulting interior anchors for the four corner strokes and delete them.

[image]